# Stepping down as provisional moderator

Tags: discussion, announcement

Hi everyone,

You may have noticed that I've not been active on the site for quite some time now. Life has kept me very busy, between getting married, moving house, looking for a new job, and moving house again!

Long story short, I felt it was only right that I step down as moderator, allowing someone else to take my place. I'll still pop in on occasion though, and hopefully I'll be able to contribute more regularly again at some point in the future.

In the meantime, I wish you all the best.

Regards,

-Peter

Comment: Thank you Peter for your service to Arduino Stack Exchange. I've had a good time working with you and sachleen and wish you luck in your future endeavors!

Comment: Thanks Peter for all you have done.

Comment: I'd also like to add my sincere thank you for all the hard work answering questions and moderating our stack. I hope you stick around as a regular user. All the best!

Comment: While I don't really know you that well, but would've liked to, I would still want to thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Thank you, Peter, for helping ASE to get a good, solid start.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for your work as moderator, Peter, and all the best for the future. If you have children you may have the chance to "moderate" their disputes, so I'm sure that your skills here will be put to good use. :)