# Please welcome your new pro tem mods!

Tags: discussion, moderation, community-moderators

As I mentioned in the [Jan 2016 beta progress report](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2310/beta-progress-update-january-2016), one of your moderators asked me about stepping down a little while ago because things were getting busier in his life outside of Arduino SE. Actually, I oversimplified a bit there; two mods are leaving the team this week. I'm happy to announce that two other users have stepped up to replace them as new pro tem mods, though:

[image: Nick Gammon]
[image: Avamander]

Please join me in [thanking Peter](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2316/stepping-down-as-provisional-moderator) and sachleen for their service and welcoming Nick and Avamander!

Comment: Greeting everyone. Thanks for the honour of assisting with moderation of this site. And thanks to Peter Bloomfield and Sachleen for their work in moderating up till now. Moderators hopefully don't have to do that much, but when they do (eg. spam) it is important.

Comment: Congratulations to both of you! We really appreciate that you are stepping up to help the site grow and thrive! We will be backing you up as we go along. Cheers!

Comment: By the way, nice going, Pops! It looks like you found some Arduino heavy-weights to lead us. Well done!

Comment: I've always wondered how @NickGammon wasn't a moderator already. `Moderators hopefully don't have to do that much` sounds funny :) but I indeed hope you still have time to write answers and articles, as I find them very in-depth and informative.

Comment: It's good to see we are poaching the quality members for rival forums ;)